# Is there a way to unserialize a php serialize string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Well i got this serialized PHP string: `a:1:{s:10:"max_photos";i:10;}` is there a way to unserialize it but with JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you need this? The much better method would be using `json_encode()` which both languages can deal with natively

Comment: Actually it's a serialized array...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [php.js](http://kvz.github.com/phpjs/) library, or simply replicate the relevant parts, although you should probably be using json_encode() as Pekka mentioned.